# how avoid clickable actions in android autocomplete textview

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to avoid clickable actions for an autocomplete Textview at particular situation in my application. My requirement is when the user click on autocomplete textview it should not display drop-down

list( means not editable ). I used ,

```
autocompletetextview.setClickable(false) 
autocompletetextview.setEnabled(false)
autocompletetextview.setFocusable(false)
```

But it doesn't work.

Please help me sort this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this to disable click action:

```
private KeyListener listener;
listener = autocompletetextview.getKeyListener();
autocompletetextview.setKeyListener(null);
```

When you want to set listener back:

```
autocompletetextview.setKeyListener(listener);
```